# Create multiple domains to download my custom plugin from wordpress.org

Tags: plugins

I am really liking this community. So far I've got some good feedback from here. Hopefully I'm also be able to contribute to others question in future.

My question is simple. I want something like this.

NL: https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/mollie-payments-for-woocommerce/

EN: https://wordpress.org/plugins/mollie-payments-for-woocommerce/

So this plugin has two domains to download the same plugin. Can anyone please suggest me how can I achieve something like this?

Comment: Both those links you posted download the exact same file. You shouldn't have different versions of your plugin in different languages, your plugin should support localisation: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/localization/

Comment: Yes I understand. Both are downloading the same file. Sorry for the misunderstanding there. But if you see although they download the same files they have different descriptions/texts one their links. One for Dutch and other one is English. My question is how can I achieve that. @JacobPeattie

Comment: So you’re just asking how to have a multilingual site? There’s many solutions out there? Have you searched and tried any? Just asking for plugin recommendations is off-topic here.

Comment: Sorry @JacobPeattie. I've done some research about this. But I'm never sure that this is a multilingual site issue and I'm still not sure about this. Because I thought multilingual site means creating a website with different languages. But this is a wordpress.org link for publishing plugins. So I thought there must be some easy way to create different domains based on language to publish plugin.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you think is the difference? The wordpress.org plugin directory is a multilingual site.

Comment: Okay. I'll check that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create subdomains and host the plugins on each site or use the one download link across all sites